# How can I print out an arraylist and also How can I add errors checks to the arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to solve this problem for ages and with no luck I didn't progress. Could someone please help me out. I have created an arrayList, made an getter class, have made a method. I can add stuff to the array list as well but when I print the arrayList out it prints out some random text.

below is the arrayList I created.

```
public static ArrayList<getArrayList> arrayList = new ArrayList<getArrayList>();
```

here is my method;

```
private static void addToArrayList(String a, double no1, int no2, int no3) {

        try {
            arrayList.add(new getArrayList(a, no1, no2, no3));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here is my getter class

```
public class getArrayList {
    private String name;
    private double seconds;
    private int speed1;
    private int speed2;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public double getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }



    public int getSpeed1() {
        return speed1;
    }



    public int getSpeed2() {
        return Speed2;
    }



    public StoreCommands(String storeName, double storeSeconds, int storeSpeed1, int storeSpeed2) throws Exception{
        name =  storeName;
        seconds = storeSeconds;
        speed1 = storeSpeed1;
        speed2 = storeSpeed2;

        }

    }
```

to add stuff on this list I use the method I created

```
addToArrayList(String a, double no1, int no2, int no3) filled in with my values
```

and to receive stuff from the arraylist I use this

```
  for(getArrayList s : arrayList) {
System.out.println(arrayList + "\n")
        ;
```

and it prints out if i use System.out.println(arrayList), depending on how much I add to the arraylist.

```
[StoreCommands@49a21b63]
```

Besides that could someone tell me how I can set a size of the arrayList so if anything more that is being added it won't add and give an error.
Also I need to perform certain error checks once the items are in the arrayList
*1st If the an item is added to the list and the user tries to add the same one again straight after I want to display an error.. (the user can add the same stuff but not directly after the one they just added, they will need to add something else first)
*2nd if say user wants to add apples to the list, I want to limit that to only 2 time in the whole list, more than that will not be added and will display and error.

Could someone help me out please, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: `StoreCommands` needs a proper `toString()`

Comment: override `toStrng()` in your `getArrayList` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for(getArrayList s : arrayList)
     System.out.println(s + "\n");//This print the tostring of getArrayList class
```

Again override the toString method of `getArrayList` class, to print actual field value of the object. Example -

```
public class getArrayList {
     public String toString(){
          return name +"||" +seconds+"||"+ speed1+"||"+speed2;
     }
}
```

Note : Follow java nomenclature standard, first later of you class name would be capital And also give a relevent name to the Class.

Comment: Hi, thanks I am starting to understand it a little now, could you please tell me where should write the second part of your code please, in my getArrayList class, should I keed everything I have, if so where do i write this? thanks again

Comment: Umm... First thing ArrayList is dynamic in behaviour, you can restrict the size, Use array for that. And implement the custom logic while adding the elements to the array like as traverse the array and check element field

Comment: Hi, figured it out. thanks thats what I needed. btw, would you know how I can perform error checks I mentioned in the question. I really need to do them and I haven't got much clue, to be honest, just started learning java and I am not too strong with it atm. I will really apprciate if you can help me out. Thanks again. Could you also please tell me how set size to the array list anything over that will not get added and provide an error.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how I can perform errors checks on the list, if something the user has entered and they try entering again it won't. So say, they type apple, they are not allowed to type apple again straight after but can do it after that. and also they cannot choose more than 2 apples in the whole arraylist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop in order to print an array, just do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayList.toArray()));
```

`ArrayList` doesn't have a mechanism to limit the size, if you want to do it - you'll have to implement it.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
/**
 * User: alfasin
 * Date: 2/5/14
 */
public class RestrictedSizeArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private static final int limit = 6;//example

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e){
        if(this.size() > 5){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Can't add more than 5 elements to the ArrayList");
        }
        boolean result = super.add(e);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  how can I implement the limit size of the arrayList, I tried this but it did not work... if arrayList <= 6      I pasted my code method where the user can store stuff in. else print an error. but this was not working, what do I need to do with the else statement. Thanks.

Comment: Hi the .toString is underlined red, do you know why?

Comment: @user3278130 My bad - I forgot the `.toArray()` - see updated answer

Comment: As for implementing a size limit, you can create a wrapper class to `ArrayList` which will override `add()` and in this method you can preform a size check before adding a new element and throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` in case the user tries to add too many elements.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding toString method will help you to print actual data. Override it in your `class getArrayList`. One more thing is class name should start with capital letter.

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Name  :  "+name+"  Seconds  : "+seconds+"  Speed1  :  "+speed1+"  Speed2  :  "+speed2;
}
```

and use it like

```
for(getArrayList s : arrayList)
   System.out.println(s.toString);
```

You can limit the size by adding check to

```
private static void addToArrayList(String a, double no1, int no2, int no3) {

        try 
        {
           if(arrayList.size < 10) //any size you want
             arrayList.add(new getArrayList(a, no1, no2, no3));
           else
             System.out.println("ArrayList is full");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for that exactly what I need, I tried this before but it was not working now it is. thanks again. do you know how I can performs the error checks I mentioned i.e. if user chooses 2 same stuff straight after another it should provide an error and if more than 2 of the same types are chosen it should not be allowed. Thanks. once again.